# Java Stream: How to map multiple value to a single DTO?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, java-stream, modelmapper

I have a List result in my Spring Boot service method as shown below:

```
Country:
String name;
List<State> states;
```

```
State:
String name;
Long population;
List<Town> towns;
```

```
Town:
String name;
```

I return Country list from my repository and it has all the related State and Town date for each Country. I want to map this data to a DTO as shown below:

```
public class CountryDTO {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Long population; //population sum of states by country

    private List<Town> towns;

    //constructor
}
```

So, how can I map my Country entity to this CountryDTO properly as explained above? I need the following data:

Country name
Sum of population by each country
Towns of each country

**Update:** Here is my service method where I tried to use Java Stream and then also ModelMapper, but cannot return desired values :(

```
List<CountryDTO> countries = countryRepository.findAll().stream()
                .flatMap(x -> x.getStates().stream())
                .map(x -> new CountryDTO(x.getCountry(), <-- need to return sum of population here -->, ObjectMapperUtils.mapAll(x.getTowns(), TownDTO.class)))
                .toList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `Stream#mapToInt` to get all the state populations and `.sum` to add them up.
- `Stream#flatMap` can be used to get all the towns of each state into a single stream.

```java
List<CountryDTO> res = countries.stream().map(c -> new CountryDTO(c.getName(), 
      c.getStates().stream().mapToInt(State::getPopulation).sum(), 
      c.getStates().stream().flatMap(s -> s.getTowns().stream()).toList())).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for this useful answer. I am trying this approach, but I just need to sum `population` as `BigDecimal` instead `Integer` and I could not using `BigDecimal::add`. Any idea for this `c.getStates().stream().mapToInt(State::getPopulation).sum()` line with BigDecimal ?

Comment: Now I am trying `c.getStates().stream().map(State::getPopulation).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add),`

Comment: @rosy `c.getStates().stream().map(s -> new BigDecimal(s.getPopulation())).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)` should do it. (You need to convert each `Long` to `BigDecimal` first.)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't get your question completely, maybe it will be more helpful if you share the exact response returned by the APIs.

But, going by the use case, if you are getting a list in the response, you always have the option of stream the list, iterate each element, and then use conditional / grouping logics to get the data in the desired way.

For example;
Let's say, you have a list of `Object` type, for which you have a repository layer configured as `ObjetRepo`. Now, if you are getting a list of objects, you can stream it like this:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectRepo objectRepo;

public List<Object> method() {
    
    
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    objectRepo.findAll().forEach(objects::add);
    // Here, instead of add, any other logic can be used.
    // You can also write a method, and use that method here
    // objectRepo.findAll().forEach(objects::someMethod);
    return objects; 
}
```